# Can I describe the fact with "You broke my computer" when my son made my computer not working while it wasn't physically damaged?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I am not sure about the usage of the word *break*. Do English native speakers use it to describe if something stops working?

Comment: Without laying blame, simply saying "it is broken" will work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, break can refer to both physical damage and something that no longer works.

> I broke my phone screen. Look at the crack!

and

> You broke my computer! It still looks okay, but it no longer turns on.

are both proper sentences.

Comment: I would definitely not use it in that way. There are plenty of more appropriate words you could use. In the case of computers there is always the question of whether a malfunction is due to a hardware or software fault. If I knew it was a software matter I would definitely not use "broke". But nor would I use it in the instance you describe. I think the most I'd say is "You appear to have damaged my computer". But diagnosis is never straightforward and you might wish to say "Since you used it my computer no longer turns on".

Comment: @WS2 well ... there goes 'blowed up' too.

Comment: @WS2 "I would definitely not use it in that way. There are plenty of more appropriate words you could use." You're overthinking this. "Broke" in this context is idiomatic and common usage among native English speakers.

Comment: @AleksandrH  "It's broke innit" is certainly "native English". All I was saying was what I, also a native English speaker, would say.

Answer (score 0):

If we are confident that the computer

> no longer works

then I believe the term "broken" is applicable regardless of whether it is a software or a hardware issue. Assuming that it "still works" and that there is a software issue, then the computer is more on the end of being  *damaged* (as referenced by @WS2) or *messed up* (more colloquial).